Excel VBA no screen update in For Next loop
I'm writing some excel VBA code to display messages on a user form. In debug mode I see the different messages, so it does pick up the correct sentences from the form, but is does not display the messages while in the for next loop. It only displays the first message and "Einde" message
For Teller1 = 1 To 20
    strHandling = Selection.Offset(Teller1, 0).Value
    If strHandling = "" Then
        lblExecution.Caption = "Einde"
        Exit For
    End If
    If strTypeLeerling = "Starter" Then
        If Teller1 = 2 Then lblChallenge.Caption = strChallenge
        lblExecution.Caption = strHandling
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    ElseIf strTypeLeerling = "Leerling" Then

Any Ideas?
I expect the individual lines to be displayed for the mentioned wait period
